# Rails validation not a number error for text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I have created an AcademicInfo model with the following migration. It has a column called remarks and the field is text field. Basically I did this for storing some kind of long text. But when I try to create an object with text, it is giving me strange kind of 'not a number error'

```
class CreateAcademicInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :academic_infos do |t|
      t.string :institution_name, null: false, default: ''
      t.string :degree, null: false, default: ''
      t.string :authority_body, null: false, default: ''
      t.text :description_of_course, null: false, default: ''
      t.date :start_date
      t.date :end_date
      t.text :remarks, null: false, default: ''
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My request message for the controller is

```
{"institution_name": "Tribhuvan Uni", "authority_body": "Nepal Gov", "description_of_course": "Lamda Lamda description", "remarks": "THis is remarks", "start_date": "2018-12-12", "end_date": "2019-12-12", "degree": "Computer Sci", "user_id": 1}
```

But I get the error

```
{
    "remarks": [
        "is not a number"
    ]
}
```

And in my model I have following validations

```
class AcademicInfo < ApplicationRecord

  validates :institution_name, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 100}
  validates :degree, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 100}
  validates :authority_body, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 100}
  validates :description_of_course, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 100}
  validates :remarks, :numericality => true, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 100}
  validates :remarks, :length => {:minimum => 5}, :allow_blank => true
  validates :start_date, :presence => true
  validates :end_date, :presence => true

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Could not figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a mistake to put numericality: true over there